# The property Item of DataGridViewCellCollection does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

The documentation of DataGridViewCellCollection states that there is a property Item for which you can use either Index or string name. When I try to use that property using DataGridViewCellCollection object the compiler displays an error that this object does not contain that property, why?

Comment: Can you post a code sample please.

Comment: `var value1 = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value;` => `var value1 = dataGridView1[2, 1].Value;` --- `var value2 = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["Column Name"].Value;` => `var value2 = dataGridView1["Column Name", 1].Value;`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit misleading. Actually it's not a property `Item`, but an indexer ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)) you can use to access the individual items. The actual definition is

```
public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell this[int index] { get; set; }
```

If you have an instance of `DataGridViewCellCollection` (named `_collection` here), you can use

```cs
private DataGridViewCell GetCell(int index)
{
    return _collection[index]; // here we're accessing the item in the cell collection
}
```

to access the elements.